# Do I need two GitHub accounts for this?

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub user account that I use for work.

I wish to upload some code that I have written outside of work and make public. Is there a way to mask my username from the public, so work could not see it was me?

Or would I need to create a separate account to upload the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the top of the GitHub help page called [What's the difference between user and organization accounts?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-s-the-difference-between-user-and-organization-accounts):

> Your user account is your identity on GitHub.

Therefore, if you don't want your workplace to be able to identify that you're the author of some personal (i.e. non-work-related) stuff that you've made public, you need to create and use a different GitHub account for that personal stuff.

For instance, use an account called `panthro_at_work` for work-related repositories and another account called `mystery_man_or_woman` for your personal stuff.

However, also be aware that

> One person or legal entity may not maintain more than one free account.

See [Account terms](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service#a-account-terms) and also [nulltoken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25429656/2541573). Therefore, in order to hold two accounts, at least one of them should be a paid account.

#### Merging accounts

Should you change your mind (at a later stage) about keeping work and personal stuff separate, GitHub allows you to merge your two user accounts; see [Merging multiple user accounts](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts).

#### Transferring repositories between accounts

GitHub allows for even more fine-grained actions than that: you can transfer ownership of only a subset of your repositories in your `mystery_man_or_woman` account to your `panthro_at_work` account (or vice versa); see [How to transfer a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/how-to-transfer-a-repository).

Comment: `One person or legal entity may not maintain more than one free account.`

They don't police that at all though, I think it's more so they can save face if anyone tries to bot or anything else untoward.

Comment: It is not an actual merge.  You are allowed to transfer repositories to the new account and then delete your old account with a complete loss of attributions.  In fact when your old account is deleted, all commits, comments, pull requests, etc you've done will be attributed to a Ghost User.

Answer (score 5):

> I wish to upload some code that I have written outside of work and make public. Is there a way to mask my username from the public, so work could not see it was me?

Any activity performed against a public repository is also public. For instance, the public activity for the user **Octocat** can be seen at the following url https://github.com/octocat?tab=activity

> Or would I need to create a separate account to upload the code?

I would advise you to take a also take a look at the GitHub **[Terms of Services](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service)** which specifically states: **"One person or legal entity may not maintain more than one free account."**

So, although the system does allow one to create multiple accounts, GitHub legally reserves the right to ban you, at its own discretion:

- *"Violation of any of the terms below will result in the termination of your Account."*
- *"The failure of GitHub to exercise or enforce any right or provision of the Terms of Service shall not constitute a waiver of such right or provision."*

Comment: Thanks, it's ok, I have one free account and one paid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a (public) organization which can own your open source repositories. If you want, you can hide the fact the organization is yours: [Publicizing or hiding organization membership](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/publicizing-or-hiding-organization-membership). It seems your membership is hidden (private) by default.

As for commit identification, you can use any email you have control of - the drawback is the commits will not be identified as yours when browsing the in the GitHub web.

This has also an advantage you can share or transfer ownership of those open source projects to another user by simply making somebody else an owner.

If you wish you can create multiple organizations, say for logical groups of your projects, or for each project in extreme case.